# Sharing folder on linux

Tags: linux, networking, file-sharing

I just want to create a sharing folder which is used from different networks.
There is no way to create with the help of Samba,

İs there any way for this issue?

192.162.2.162 -----> Folder <----------10.1.1.20

Comment: What is your problem with samba? Your question is not clear.

Comment: a folder will be reached from two different netwotrks. Is there any way? 192.162.2.162 -----> Folder <----------10.1.1.20

Comment: What is the relation of this with samba? If you setup your network right, you should be able to reach the folder.

Comment: is there any way to create a file which is shared between us(you and me) ?

Comment: Yes if you give me your IP address and it is allowed for me to reach this IP.

Comment: Are you trying to share between two networks, or trying to share to the Internet? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: but how dude :)

Comment: ı have  two different ip adrress from different networks.For exm.                                       10.1.1.20 and 192.168.2.165                                                       Both of them dont have any configurations for internet. Just use autodesk. And ıjust want to create a folder which will be used just for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a share issue. It's a bridging the networks issue. You need to have it set up so that the two networks are routed in a way to see each other, either through a router or a computer with two network interfaces configured to act as a router. Then when traffic is destined for the other network, the router handles the translation.

Or you set up a VPN to bridge the networks, in which case you're still dealing with a routing issue.

Then you just set up your share and connect to it by mapping; easiest would be by IP, but if you have an internal DNS server you could connect by name.